# strtok() then strcmp() returning false when true

Tags: c, strtok

I'm guessing this is a type issue, so maybe you can show me how it is correctly done.

I'm reading command inputs from `stdin` and I want to quit when the user enters `q`.

I'm reading a user input from `stdin` using `fgets()` into a pointer to a character array. Then I splice off the first word using `strtok()` and assign it to another pointer to a character array. Then I compare it to a `q` in order to see if the user wants to quit the program by using the `strcmp()` function.

Here is some code:

```
    char *input = (char*)malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
    char *command = (char*)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    while (strcmp(command, "q") != 0)
    {
        memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
        printf("Enter command: ");
        fgets(input, 64, stdin);
        command = strtok(input, " ");
        //if I enter q --> printf("%d", strcmp(command, "q")) == 10
        //if I enter w --> printf("%d", strcmp(command, "q")) == 6
    }
```

What I want is, if `command == q` then `printf("%d", strcmp(command, "q"))` should equal `0` else it should print any other integer.

I should also note that I have verified `command` is being correctly assigned. In other words, when I enter `q`, `command == "q"`.

Comment: if your command contains "q" how will it enter the while loop because the condition will be false.

Comment: 1) `char *input = malloc(64);` 2) `char *command = "";` 3) `//memset(input, 0, 64);` 4) `command = strtok(input, " \n");`

Comment: you can't read 64 from stdin, while your input is of 32 bytes. Correct this.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY good catch on the size

Comment: And `free`ing after use is a good habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *input = (char*)malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
    char *command = (char*)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));

    while (strcmp(command, "q") != 0)
    {
        memset(input, 0, sizeof(input));
        printf("Enter command: ");
        fgets(input, 64, stdin);
        command = strtok(input, " \n"); // Line corrected.
        //if I enter q --> printf("%d", strcmp(command, "q")) == 10
        //if I enter w --> printf("%d", strcmp(command, "q")) == 6
    }

return 0;

}
```

Comment: a space has to be the delimiter because the program accepts other commands such as `pd 2 4`. I thought `(char*)malloc(64 * sizeof(char))` might have done it, but still no luck -- still returns `10` and not `0`

Comment: strtok will split with spaces OR linefeed: it works (although there are useless lines in your code: no need to allocate `command` + 32/64 size problems)

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `64` with `fgets()` when you allocate `32` with `malloc()` — it will lead to great unhappiness when you enter more than 31 characters of input.

Comment: 1.) The code invokes undefined behaviour when 1st executing this line `while (strcmp(command, "q") != 0)` as the memory `command` points had not been initialised. 2.) The code leaks the memory allocated here: `char *command = (char*)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));` the moment this line `command = strtok(input, " \n");` gets execute as the one and only reference to the memory allocated is overwritten and with this it's lost. 3.) All those casts are useless, at least as long you do C and not C++-.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues here.

1. The memory allocated here

   ```
   char *command = (char*)malloc(8 * sizeof(char));
   ```

   leaks the moment this line

   ```
   command = strtok(input, " ");
   ```

   gets execute as the one and only reference to the memory allocated gets overwritten and therefore lost.
2. A possible buffer overflow can occur here

   ```
   fgets(input, 64, stdin);
   ```

   as allowing to read more bytes (64) ito `input` as it points to be the allocation done here

   ```
   char *input = (char*)malloc(32 * sizeof(char));
   ```
3. Assuming the data input by the user does not contain a sequence like '[blanks]q ...`then`command`get assigned`NULL` by this call

   ```
   command = strtok(input, " ");
   ```

   which leads to passing `NULL` to `strcmp()` here on testing for next iteration here

   ```
   while (strcmp(command, "q") != 0)
   ```

   Doing so invoke undefined behaviour.
4. The code misses to check the outcome of relevant function calls, like ``` malloc()`` and ```fgets()`.
5. Casting the result of `malloc()` & friends isn't needed in C nor is it recommended in way. So just do not do it. It might very well hide errors.
6. `sizeof (char)` is defined to be `1`. No need to use it.
7. Do not spoil you code with "Magic Numbers"/"Tokens" like `32`, `8`, `64`, `"q"` ...
8. Using while-loop conceptionally is the wrong approach if you want to perform a certain action *at least once*. In such cases use a do-while loop.

Fixing all this might lead to the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE (64)
#define QUIT_STRING "q"


int main(void)
{
  int result = EXIT_SUCCESS; /* Be optimistic. */

  char *input = malloc(INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof *input);
  if (NULL == input)
  {
    perror("malloc () failed");
    result = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  else
  {
    char *command;

    do 
    {
      printf("Enter command:\n");
      if (NULL == fgets(input, INPUT_BUFFER_SIZE, stdin))
      {
        if (!feof(stdin))
        {
          result = EXIT_FAILURE;
          fprintf(stderr, "fgets() failed.\n");
        } 

        break;
      }

      command = strtok(input, " \n"); 
    } while ((command == NULL) || strcmp(command, QUIT_STRING) != 0);

    if (NULL != command)
    {
      printf("User quit.\n");
    }

    free(input);
  }

  return result;
}
```